# Android remove polyline from map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am drawing a `polyline` on map on like an animation. like below.

```
m_handler = new Handler();
        m_handlerTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //line.remove();
                if (t < pointsPoly.size() - 1) {

                    LatLng src = pointsPoly.get(t);
                    LatLng dest = pointsPoly.get(t + 1);
                    Polyline lineAnimation = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                                    new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                            .width(10).color(Color.DKGRAY).geodesic(true));
                    t++;

                } else {
                    t = 0;

                }
                m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, polyLineTimer);
            }
        };
        m_handler.post(m_handlerTask);
```

How can i remove the `polyline`? I don't want to `clearMap()`. 
I tried `lineAnimation.remove();` but its not working.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't adding that polyline multiple time? So when you tried to remove it, there is another one underneath that makes you think it never got deleted?

Comment: I'd tried storing them in an ArrayList every times I create one, then when deletion is needed, iterate through that array and delete them...

Comment: @jaythakin can you please send me an example of adding and removing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just do the following but instead of assign the result to a variable, put it in an ArrayList...

```
    ArrayList<Polyline> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add line to map
    lines.add(mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),
                        new LatLng(this.destinationLatitude, this.destinationLongitude))
                .width(1)
                .color(Color.DKGRAY));

    //Remove the same line from map
    line.remove();
```

> Removes this polyline from the map. After a polyline has been removed,
>   the behavior of all its methods is undefined.

Comment: thanks for quick ans. I don't know how to add polyline in arraylist and show on map :(. That solution what I need :(

Comment: Thank you so much....... I will try it tomorrow and will let you know.Thank you again man.

Comment: Thank you so much... it's working :) And for remove PolyLine I did like this. for (Polyline line : polylines) { line.remove(); } polylines.clear();